# How to sort 2D arrays row-wise?

Tags: c#, sorting

I want to sort this 2D array of chemicals names with their corresponding numbers in descending order. The first half of the algorithm is working by placing Nitrogen at the top and Sulphur at the second-top. The last two i.e Hydrogen and Ammonia however, are not swapping rows with each other.

```
String[,] chem = new String[4, 2];
chem[0, 0] = "Hydrogen";
chem[0, 1] = "221";
chem[1, 0] = "Sulphur";
chem[1, 1] = "431";
chem[2, 0] = "Ammonia";
chem[2, 1] = "332";
chem[3, 0] = "Nitrogen";
chem[3, 1] = "688";
string temp, temp2;
int key = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        key = 0;
        for (int p = i - 1; p >= 0 && key != 1;)
        {
            if (int.Parse(chem[i, 1]) > int.Parse(chem[j, 1]))
            {
                temp = chem[i, 1];
                chem[i, 1] = chem[j, 1];
                chem[j, 1] = temp;
                temp2 = chem[i, 0];
                chem[i, 0] = chem[j, 0];
                chem[j, 0] = temp2;
            }
            else { key = 1; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using a Dictionary or at least [ValueKeyPairs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.8) it would fit your task better IMO, also sorting would be easier.

Comment: Take a look at [these](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/166236/Sorting-a-Two-Dimensional-Array-in-Csharp) extension methods.

Comment: Always avoid stringly typing.  Get ahead by declaring a `Chemical` class with a string and int property.  Which gets you to a simple `Chemical[]` array that is easy to sort.  Which easily gets you to a more suitable collection type, like `List<Chemical>` or `Dictionary<string, Chemical>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of points:

- Your variable `p` is not being referenced or updated anywhere, so the innermost `for` loop is effectively doing `while(key != 1)`
- Your `j = 0` to `j < 2`  for loop initially looks sensible (i and j are usually used for different indices, and your array is `new String[4, 2];`) - but you're actually using these for the same index. You probably want to run `j` from `j = 0` to `j < 4` instead of `j = 0` to `j < 2`

Haven't been able to test this - apologies

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You're a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you want **2D array** like this (are you looking for `Dictionary<string, int>`?); if you insist on it, we can turn the array into more convenient collection:

```
 List<Tuple<string, int>> data = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

 for(int i = 0; i < chem.GetLength(0); ++i)
   data.Add(Tuple.Create(chem[i, 0], int.Parse(chem[i, 1])));
```

Then sort `data` with a help of `OrderBy` / `OrderByDescending` and put values back to `chem`

```
 using System.Linq;

 ... 

 int index = 0;

 foreach (var tuple in data.OrderByDescending(item => item.Item2)) {
   chem[index, 0] = tuple.Item1; 
   chem[index, 1] = tuple.Item2.ToString();

   index += 1; 
 }
```

Finally, let's extract a method:

```
private static void SortChem(string[,] chem) {
  List<Tuple<string, int>> data = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

  for(int i = 0; i < chem.GetLength(0); ++i)
    data.Add(Tuple.Create(chem[i, 0], int.Parse(chem[i, 1]))); 

  int index = 0;

  foreach (var tuple in data.OrderByDescending(item => item.Item2)) {
    chem[index, 0] = tuple.Item1; 
    chem[index, 1] = tuple.Item2.ToString();

    index += 1; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but for the time being, I'm bound to do this task on 2D array. Can you check my code?

Comment: @GracefulFantasy: I doubt if you should *reinvent the wheel* and implement (and debug) *your own sort* when we have `Sort` for `List<T>` and `Array`, `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` for `IEnumerable<T>`... you current implementation is *slow* (*nested loops* `i` and `j`); have magic constant `4` in `for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)` which will cause problems for shorter and longer arrays

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, more readable, albeit more resource-hungry

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for (int i = 0; i < chem.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    dict.Add(chem[i, 0], chem[i, 1]);
}

var reverse_dict = dict.Reverse().ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < chem.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    chem[i, 0] = reverse_dict[i].Key;
    chem[i, 1] = reverse_dict[i].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here there is an alternative solution.I hope it can be useful.Dictionary will help you instead of array.

```
var chems = new Dictionary<int, string>();
chems.Add(221, "Hydrogen");
chems.Add(431,"Sulphur");
chems.Add(332, "Ammonia");
chems.Add(688, "Nitrogen");
var order = chems.Keys.ToList();
order.Sort();
foreach (var chem in order)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",chem,chems[chem]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```